# Keep only N characters of specific column

Tags: linux, awk, csv

I'm trying to treat a CSV file in away that I'll keep only the first 10 characters of a specific column values.

The field values are inside "" and has a comma in the middle which give me errors and that I was able to fix, but I'm not able to retrieve and keep only the first 10 characters of the field  after that. The columns are on the indexes 12 and 17. Here's how I've tried:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2)
                           if ($i == 12 || $i == 17)
                             print substr($i,index($0,$9))
                           else  gsub(",", "", $i)
} 1' $1 > testTREATED.csv
```

I have something like this on the CSV:

```
ID,ID_CUSTOMER,CUSTOMER_FULLNAME,TYPE_DOCUMENT,NUM_DOCUMENT,CUSTOMER_NAME,LASTNAME1_CUSTOMER,LASTNAME2_CUSTOMER,F_UID,L_UID,ID_LIST,ID_ACCOUNT,DATE_OF_BIRTH,CASE,ANALIST,COMMENTS,COMMENTS2,START_DATE,ORGUNIT_ID,AMOUNT,TYPE
0001,,SWISS CHOCOLATE LTD,,,,SWISS CHOCOLATE LTD,,,000000-000000,XX,,,,,,,"25/06/2007 23:45:65, 000000000",0,,
```

and I want the date field to be like this:

```
25/06/2007
```

Can anybody help me with that? :)
Thanks!

Comment: Two things: awk would treat the internal commas as delimiters too, and you are testing the values of the columns against 12 and 17, not the column indexes (and the variable will furthermore never be 17).

Comment: please paste some row of your file and which result you expect.

Comment: I have something like this:

ID, NAME, ADDRESS, DOCUMENT_TYPE, DATE_OF_BIRTH, COMMENTS, START_DATE

where both DATE_OF_BIRTH and START_DATE contains values like this:

"25/06/2007 23:45:65, 000000000"

and I want them like this:

25/06/2007

Comment: @Bord_up please [edit] your question to include this information rather than posting it in comments

Comment: @steeldriver done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about `awk -F,  'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS=","} {print $1,$2,$3,$4,substr($5,2,10),$7,substr($8,2,10)}' YourFileName`